# Blank page after deploying React project

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, web-deployment

First the following was added to the package.json:

`"homepage": "."`

and

```
`"predeploy": "npm run build",

"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`
```

in the `"scripts"` part.

Then,
`"start_url": "."` in the manifest file.

Next,

`npm install gh-pages --save-dev`

Then I pushed the code to my [Github](https://github.com/DMorrisonASC/ReactJS-TodoList) before deploying it to using `npm run deploy`

In Github repository, "gh pages branch." was selected

However, there only a blank page. I suspect that the homepage is not correct because the `index.html` is in "*...\react-todo-list\src\index.js*".

Answer (score 0):

I followed this very descriptive [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wDzEjXbblM)

1) It turns outs that I needed to change `"homepage": "."` to 
`"homepage": "https://dmorrisonasc.github.io/ReactJS-TodoList/"`.

2) And change my the import of route component( `BrowserRouter as Router` to `HashRouter as Router`) in my index.js file.

3) Re-deploy